# How to configure properties in a distributed JMeter system

Tags: jmeter

We have a highly parameterized JMeter job, and we define all those parameters (things like number of users and length of simulation) in a Java properties file that we specify on the command line

> jmeter -n -t myscript.jmx -p 500users.props

but when we tried to distribute this over several machines:

> jmeter -n -t myscript.jmx -p 500users.props -Rmachine1,machine2,machine3

those machines did not see the value specified in the properties file.  How do you configure your JMeter tests in a distributed scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently you need to use the -G flag to get things to other servers.

> jmeter -n -t myscript.jmx **-G**500users.props -Rmachine1,machine2,machine3